# merge sort implementation 7

Tags: c, mergesort

Please look at the above code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void mergesort(int *,int ,int);
void merge1(int *,int ,int ,int);

int main()
{
int low=0,high,n,i,a[100];

  printf("Enter the lenght of array\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  high =n-1;
  printf("Enter the array that you want to sort\n");

  for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }

  mergesort(a,low,high);
  printf("The sorted array is \n");

  for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
  {
    printf("%d-",a[i]);
  }
  printf("MERGE sorted");
  return 0;
}

void mergesort(int a[],int low,int high)

{

  int mid;
  if(low<high)
 {
    mid=(low+high)/2;
    mergesort(a,low,mid);
    mergesort(a,mid+1,high);
    merge1(a,low,mid,high);
 }

}

 void merge1(int a[],int low,int mid,int high)
{
    int i=low,j=mid+1,new_array[100],k=low,m;

      while(i<=mid && j<=high)
   {
     if(a[i]<a[j]) 
     {
       new_array[k]=a[i];
       i++;
       k++;
     }
    else
    {
       new_array[k]=a[j];
       j++;
       k++;

    }
   }

        while(i<=mid)
       {
       new_array[k]=a[i];
       i++;k++;
       }

       while(j<=high) 
      {
       new_array[k]=a[j];
       j++;
       k++;
      }

      for(m=low;m<=high;m++)
     {
         a[m]=new_array[m];
     } 

}
```

Actually, I implemented merge sort and it is working fine but I want much better code than this . Can anyone  make this code much better?

Comment: Do you want the *merge sort algorithm* to be better, or do you want the *sorting* to be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Coding conventions**

1. It is more customary to put **one** space character **before** and **after** a binary operator. So instead of `a=1`, you should write `a = 1`.
2. `int low=0,high,n,i,a[100];` This is not easy to read, so instead, declare each variable on its own row:

```
    int low = 0;
    int high;
    .
    .
    .
```

**Implementation**

1. `new_array[100]` This substantially limits your implementation. Of course, in C, you can always overflow it, but it may rewrite relevant data or terminate your program altogether in case your process references a memory location it may not.
2. `mid=(low+high)/2;` This is a minor nitpick, yet some people suggest writing `mid = low + (high - low) / 2`. That may avoid overflowing `low + high` in some (super rare) cases.

**General comments**

Otherwise, your implementation looks reasonable as you don't write an `if` hell some novices tend to.

**Summa summarum**

After mainly correcting the style issues, you may come out with something like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void merge(int* a, int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int i = low;
    int j = mid + 1;
    int k = 0;
    int m;

    int* new_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (high - low + 1));

    while (i <= mid && j <= high)
    {
        if (a[i] < a[j])
        {
            new_array[k++] = a[i++];
        }
        else
        {
            new_array[k++] = a[j++];
        }
    }

    while (i <= mid)
    {
        new_array[k++] = a[i++];
    }

    while (j <= high)
    {
        new_array[k++] = a[j++];
    }

    for (m = low, k = 0; m <= high; m++, k++)
    {
        a[m] = new_array[k];
    }

    free(new_array);
}

void my_mergesort(int a[], int low, int high)
{
    int mid;

    if (low < high)
    {
        mid= low + (high - low) / 2;
        my_mergesort(a, low, mid);
        my_mergesort(a, mid + 1, high);
        merge(a, low, mid, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int high;
    int n;
    int i;
    int a[100];

    printf("Enter the lenght of array\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    high = n;

    printf("Enter the array that you want to sort\n");

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    my_mergesort(a, 0, n - 1);

    printf("The sorted array is \n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    }

    puts("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: please explain the overflow with low and mid that you have mentioned in your comment i.e `mid=(low+high)/2 ` should be written like            `mid = low + (high - low) / 2` ?

Comment: Assume that an `int` is a signed 4-byte integer. For the sake of an example, assume that `low == 1_000_000_000` and `high == 2_000_000_000`. The `mid` should be 1_500_000_000, but it will, in fact, be -1294967296, and the `mid` ends up being negative.